# A list of values (multiple values) with gcloud (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tags, gcloud, google-cloud-run, revision

I'm trying to remove **two tags "green" and "yellow"** from **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"** on **Cloud Run**:

[image]

But when I ran the command with **a list of two values "green" and "yellow"** as shown below to remove **two tags "green" and "yellow"** from **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor /
  --remove-tags=[green,yellow]
              // A list of 2 values
```

These two tags were not removed:

[image]

Even though [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/services/update-traffic#--remove-tags) says as shown below:

> --remove-tags=[`TAG`,…]
>
> List of tags to be removed.

But when I ran the command with **one value "green"** as shown below to remove **one tag "green"** from **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags=green
             // One value
```

I could remove **one tag "green"**:

[image]

So, is it possible to remove **two tags "green" and "yellow"** from **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"** with the command which has **a list of two values "green" and "yellow"**? If possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command without using **square brackets "[]" as shown below**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags=green,yellow
            // "[]" are removed
```

Then, **two tags "green" and "yellow"** are removed from **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"**:

[image]

In addition, if there are one or more empty strings before or after a comma in a list, there is an error.

So, if an empty string is before a comma:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags=green ,yellow
                  // An empty string before a comma
```

Then, there is an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update-traffic) unrecognized arguments: ,yellow

And if an empty string is after a comma:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor 
  --remove-tags=green, yellow
                   // An empty string after a comma
```

Then, there is an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update-traffic) unrecognized arguments: yellow

So, don't put one or more empty strings before or after a comma in a list:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags=green,yellow
                  // No empty strings 
                  // before or after a comma
```

In addition again, you can remove **"=" just right to "--remove-tags"** but it still works:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags green,yellow
           // "=" is removed 
           // but it still works
```